# jOOQ very slow at startup

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jooq, hikaricp

I have an application built in spring boot 2.1.2 and spring-data-jpa with hibernate (MariaDB).

Recently I successfull introduced `jOOQ (3.11.9)` to test a massive insert/update and it greatly reduces the insert times (hibernate with pk autoincrement disables the bulk insert).

In development, however, the application has greatly increased the start-up times (from 22 seconds to 80+ seconds).

Increasing the level of the logs I can see the istructions where the start slows down:

```
2019-12-12 12:48:32.580 TRACE 8960 --- [  restartedMain] .PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource : Looking for Pre/Post annotations for method 'dsl' on target class 'class org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext'
2019-12-12 12:48:32.580 TRACE 8960 --- [  restartedMain] .PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource : No expression annotations found
2019-12-12 12:48:32.580 TRACE 8960 --- [  restartedMain] .PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource : Looking for Pre/Post annotations for method 'close' on target class 'class org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext'
2019-12-12 12:48:32.581 TRACE 8960 --- [  restartedMain] .PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource : No expression annotations found
2019-12-12 12:49:01.858 DEBUG 8960 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
2019-12-12 12:49:19.248 DEBUG 8960 --- [alina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase  : Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1576151359246 sessioncount 0
2019-12-12 12:49:19.248 DEBUG 8960 --- [alina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase  : End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 2 expired sessions: 0
2019-12-12 12:49:31.860 DEBUG 8960 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
2019-12-12 12:49:56.970 TRACE 8960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'dsl'
2019-12-12 12:49:56.970 TRACE 8960 --- [  restartedMain] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowiring by type from bean name 'lstVendorListService' to bean named 'dsl'
2019-12-12 12:49:56.970 TRACE 8960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'metaDataSourceAdvisor'
```

The number of jOOQ entities does not change time of start-up.

Has anyone ever experienced a similar problem?

Comment: This is usually an instrumentation problem caused by Spring rather than jOOQ. Are you using Spring to (accidentally) scan jOOQ classes?

Comment: Hi Lukas,I thought the same thing but when I deleted all the entities except one, the problem persist.

Comment: What I meant by that is that Spring seems to be using those entities as an instrumentation starting point to then instrument the entire jOOQ API, and something goes wrong when it does that. You could use a profiler to verify this...